# How to position ngx-slider handle for vertical slider?

Tags: css, angular

I saw a few examples of custom CSS for ngx-slider but none of them is using the vertical mode.

I don't know why but my handle appears next to the bar instead of on the bar. I forced the component to a fixed width (with a background).

Doc of the official module regarding CSS:
https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/blob/master/STYLING.md

I saw online the example of changing top:

```
.custom-ngx-slider .ngx-slider .ngx-slider-pointer {
      width: 10px;
      height: 15px;
      top: auto; /* to remove the default positioning */
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

But that does not change anything in vertical, I also tried using `left` and `right` without success.

Here is the module CSS : https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/blob/master/src/ngx-slider/lib/slider.component.scss

Here is what I get by default (we can see that the bar of `*-out-selection` is taking the whole width while the actual `ngx-slider` background is only half of it (set by CSS at 16px)):

[image]

```
.ngx-slider-pointer {
  width: 14px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1;
  cursor: move;
}
.ngx-slider-pointer:after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: please explain the difference of on the bar and above the bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ngx-slider-pointer {
  left: 0px!important;
}
```

The original code shifts the handles with `left: -$barDimension!important;` so even modifying `left` was not working, until I added `!important`.